# REGEX using gawk command

Tags: linux, awk

In Linux, I'm running the command

```
pmap -x $PID | tail -n 1
```

This gives me a line like the following:

```
total kB         168194812  870692  852296
```

I'm trying to extract the 2nd number (rss) for use.  I found this example that works in regex101.com:

```
/[^\d]*[\d]+[\s]+([\d]+)/
```

However, when I try to run it against my line of text I don't get any print output:

```
echo "total kB         168194812  870692  852296" | gawk 'match($0, /[^\d]*[\d]+[\s]+([\d]+)/, a) {print a[1]}'
```

I'm expecting it to print

```
870692
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
$ pmap -x $PID | gawk 'match($0, /[^0-9]*[0-9]+\s+([0-9]+)/, a) {print a[1]}'
870692
```

The expression `\d` is specific Perl/PCRE compatible regex. Some languages like Python use this too.

You can simplify to:

```
awk '{print $4}'
```

Using [grep](/questions/tagged/grep):

```
grep -oP '\d+(?=\s+\d+$)'
```

Answer (score 2):

What about just displaying the 4th field with

```
awk '{print $4}'
```

With your example

```
echo "total kB         168194812  870692  852296" | awk '{print $4}'
```

returns

```
870692
```

Comment: Already answered earlier https://stackoverflow.com/a/74606824/465183

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `grep` and with your shown samples please try following `grep` code. Here is the complete [Online regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xWyO6J/1) for used regex.

```bash
echo "total kB         168194812  870692  852296" |
grep -oP '^total kB\s+\d+\s+\K\d+'
```

***Explanation:***

- I am using `-oP` options of GNU `grep` here, which are for exact matching and enabling PCRE regex flavour respectively.
- Then in main `grep` program I am using regex `^total kB\s+\d+\s+\K\d+` where:
- Matching `total kB` from starting of the value followed by spaces followed by digits followed by spaces.
- Then using `\K` option to forget values whatever matched till now by regex, this will help us to get the required output, though it matches the regex but doesn't consider values in output printing.
- Then matching 1 or more digits which is our required output.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `awk` you can match digits with `[0-9]` and the negated version `[^0-9]`

As you output a single line with `tail -n 1`, using `gnu awk` you could also set the row separator to 1 or more digits, and print the row terminator when the row number is 2.

```
echo "total kB         168194812  870692  852296" | 
awk -v RS='[0-9]+' 'NR == 2 {print RT}'
```

Output

```
870692
```